# Why ++str and str+1 is working and str++ isn't?

Tags: c, recursion, c-strings, post-increment, function-declaration

I know that here are some explanations about the difference between p++, ++p and p+1 but I couldn't understand it clearly yet, especially when it's not working with that function:

```
void replace(char * str, char c1, char c2){

    if (*str == '\0') {
        return;
    }else if (*str == c1) {
        printf("%c", c2);
    }
    else {
        printf("%c", *str);
    }

    replace(++str, c1, c2);
}
```

When I do `replace(++str, c1, c2);` or `replace(str+1, c1, c2);` it works, but `replace(str++, c1, c2);` doesn't. Why?

Comment: Besides the question of which increment works, there is no point in incrementing `str` at all, since `str` is no longer used after `replace`. The natural way to write it would be simply `replace(str + 1, c1, c2)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replace(str++, c1, c2);` means:

```
replace(str, c1, c2);
str+=1;
```

while `replace(++str, c1, c2);` means:

```
str+=1;
replace(str, c1, c2);
```

Answer (score 4):

The expression `str++` yields the value before incrementing its operand. So you are calling the function with the same value of str.

From the C Standard (6.5.2.4 Postfix increment and decrement operators)

> 2 **The result of the postfix ++ operator is the value of the
>   operand**. As a side effect, the value of the operand object is
>   incremented (that is, the value 1 of the appropriate type is added to
>   it)

You may consider this function call

```
replace(str++, c1, c2);
```

like

```
replace(str, c1, c2);
str += 1;
```

In two other calls

```
replace(++str, c1, c2);
```

and

```
replace(str+1, c1, c2);
```

you are passing incremented value of the string pointer.

Pay attention to that your function does not replace characters in the source string. It just outputs the string replacing characters in the output. The source string is not changed

In this case the first function parameter should be declared with the qualifier const.

```
void replace(const char * str, char c1, char c2);
```

If you want to change the source string then the function can look as it is shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

char * replace( char *s, char c1, char c2 )
{
    if ( *s && *s == c1 ) *s = c2;

    if ( *s ) replace( s + 1, c1, c2 );

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "Lucy is learning c";

    puts( replace( s, 'c', 'C' ) );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
LuCy is learning C
```

Answer (score 2):

Both the prefix `++` operator and the postfix `++` operator increment the argument.  The difference is in the result of the expression.

The prefix `++` evaluates to the value of the argument *after* incrementing, while the postfix `++` evaluates to the value of the argument *before* incrementing.

For example:

```
int i = 1;
printf("i=%d\n", ++i);   // i == 2, prints 2
printf("i=%d\n", i++);   // i == 3, prints 2
```

Answer (score 2):

`++str` and `str+1` makes the the pointer point to the next byte, while the `str++` passes the current location of the pointer as an argument.